# sstableloader not loading data into DSE 4.5.1 Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I have SSTables copied from a source placed here : 
`/dev/shm/datafiles/node1/ppr/online_inv`

When I run SSTable loader to load the data , it runs and terminates within a second without loading the data .

```
[cassandra@nmd bin]$ ./sstableloader --debug  -d 10.241.17.107 /dev/shm/datafiles/node1/ppr/online_inv
```

Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Streaming relevant part of `/dev/shm/datafiles/node1/ppr/online_inv/ppr-online_inv-jb-546-Data.db` to []
Streaming session ID: `86e92720-815c-11e6-b0c0-45a6be0356e5`

This is a new DSE 4.5.1 cluster and we just began loading data through prod sstables . Schema is already created just like prod cluster from where we have copied sstables. This is happening for all keyspaces/tables.

We also tried jmxsh method but this is also getting terminated in the same way as sstable loader :

`INFO [RMI TCP Connection(14)-10.241.17.107] 2016-09-23 07:02:01,482 OutputHandler.java (line 42) Streaming relevant part of /dev/shm/datafiles/node3/look/look_details/look-look_details-jb-1240-Data.db /dev/shm/datafiles/node3/look/look_details/look-look_details-jb-1239-Data.db /dev/shm/datafiles/node3/look/look_details/look-look_details-jb-1237-Data.db /dev/shm/datafiles/node3/look/look_details/look-look_details-jb-1236-Data.db /dev/shm/datafiles/node3/look/look_details/look-look_details-jb-1235-Data.db to []`

Comment: The issue was related to snitch settings which picked up default names of DC and rack as 'Cassandra' & 'rack1' . Altered the schema definition and problem was resolved .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to snitch settings which picked up default names of DC and rack as 'Cassandra' & 'rack1' . Altered the schema definition and problem was resolved .